# product add to cart after loading the product ajax call

Tags: cart, addtocart, mini-cart, ajaxaddtocart

How to trigger add to cart function After loading product by Ajax call.

[image]

this above product loaded by ajax call I have to found solution if I click add to cart button, then add to cart function triggered.
Kindly help me to find solution

Answer (score 0):

1st step: in phtml where product is displaying

> $addToCartUrl =  $block->getAddToCartUrl($products);

Here $products is object of a \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory class.

> $this->product->create()->load($productId);

2nd step: In Block paste

> public function getAddToCartUrl($product)
> {
> return $this->listProductBlock->getAddToCartUrl($product);
> }

Where listProductBlock is object of

> Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct

Class

3rd Step: in phtml again paste this code for "Add To Cart" button

```
<form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php echo $addToCartUrl; ?>" method="post"> 
        <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
        <div class="btn">
            <button type="submit" title="Add to Cart" class="action tocart primary">
                <span>Add to Cart</span>
            </button>
        </div>   
     </form>
```

Step 4: In etc/frontend/sections.xml:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
```

Please let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: Thank you for providing me solution but it not work for me, because after adding product to cart it response JSON file.

Comment: Can you please explain more, also please see my updated answer.

Comment: i am saying that when i click add to cart button than browser show JSON output on the screen while product add to cart successfully. i want this output not show by screen.

Comment: I gave the answer you asked about add to cart functionality, if it is working please accept as a answer. Also, for your next question can you please create another query with more details so I can look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, settings) {
    if (settings.url.indexOf("customer/section/load/?sections=cart") > 0) {
       alert("product added in basket")
    }  
});
```